# An element of $A_4$ has order $1,2$ or $3$. Use this fact to prove that the centre of $A_4$ is trivial

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> An element of $A_4$ has order $1, 2 \space$ or $\space 3$. Use this fact to prove that the centre $Z(A_4)$ of $A_4$ is equal to $[e]$.

This is clear if we construct the Cayley table for $A_4$, but any ideas as to how to prove it else wise?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: If elements of coprime order commute, the order of their product is ....

Spoiler:

> In this case a non-trivial element in the center would imply the presence of an element of order six, because the central element would commute with both elements of order 2 and of order 3, and its own order is coprime to one of those.